# Putting a circle on the map where the user clicks in qml

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I am trying to get my .qml map to display a circle where the user clicks however keep tying myself in knots. The window output the coordinates to the spinboxes in GeoWidget properly, however I want a circle to appear in that location so the user has some feedback.

coord_map.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.0
import Fluid.Controls 1.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Item {
width: 600
height: 600

Map {
    id: map

    anchors.fill: parent
    zoomLevel: 6
    center: (0, 0)

    MapItemView {
            model: src
            delegate: MapQuickItem {
                coordinate: src.position.coordinate

                anchorPoint.x: image.width * 0.5
                anchorPoint.y: image.height

                sourceItem: Column {
                    Image { id: image; source: "marker.png" }
                    Text { text: title; font.bold: true }
                }
            }
        }

    MapCircle {
            id: circle
            radius: parent.width/10
            border.width: 1
            color: 'green'
        }

    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouse
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {controller.update_from_map(map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)))
                    circle.center(map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)))
                }

    plugin: Plugin {
        name: "osm"
    }

}

}
```

coordbox.py

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide2.QtCore import Property, Signal, Slot, Qt, QUrl
from PySide2.QtPositioning import QGeoCoordinate
from PySide2.QtQuickWidgets import QQuickWidget
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QDialog,
    QDialogButtonBox,
    QDoubleSpinBox,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QToolButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    QWizard,
    QWizardPage,
)

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


# TODO: Give the user feedback on where their coordinate is when clicked
class MapDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, geo_widget):
        super().__init__(geo_widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Map")
        self.map_widget = QQuickWidget(resizeMode=QQuickWidget.SizeRootObjectToView)
        self.map_widget.rootContext().setContextProperty("controller", geo_widget)
        filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "coord_map.qml")
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
        self.map_widget.setSource(url)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox()
        button_box.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        button_box.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QDialogButtonBox.Ok)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.map_widget)
        lay.addWidget(button_box)

        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)


class GeoWidget(QWidget):
    coordinate_changed = Signal(name="coordinateChanged")

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._coordinate = QGeoCoordinate(0, 0)

        self._lat_spinbox = QDoubleSpinBox(
            minimum=49.0, maximum=56.0  # , valueChanged=self.handle_value_changed,
        )
        self._lng_spinbox = QDoubleSpinBox(
            minimum=-8, maximum=2  # , valueChanged=self.handle_value_changed,
        )
        self.btn = QToolButton(text="Map", clicked=self.handle_clicked)
        self.map_view = MapDialog(self)

        # self.coordinate_changed.connect(self.handle_value_changed)
        # self.coordinate_changed.connect(self.handle_value_changed)
        lay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(QLabel("Latitude:"))
        lay.addWidget(self._lat_spinbox)
        lay.addWidget(QLabel("Longitude:"))
        lay.addWidget(self._lng_spinbox)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn)

    @Property(QGeoCoordinate, notify=coordinate_changed)
    def coordinate(self):
        return self._coordinate

    @coordinate.setter
    def coordinate(self, coordinate):
        if self.coordinate == coordinate:
            return
        self._coordinate = coordinate
        self.coordinate_changed.emit()

    def handle_value_changed(self):
        coordinate = QGeoCoordinate(
            self._lat_spinbox.value(), self._lng_spinbox.value()
        )
        self.coordinate = coordinate

    @Slot(QGeoCoordinate)
    def update_from_map(self, coordinate):
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self._lat_spinbox.setValue(self.coordinate.latitude())
        self._lng_spinbox.setValue(self.coordinate.longitude())

    def handle_clicked(self):
        self.map_view.exec_()


# Rest of code is used to debug this coordinate box

class WizardPage(QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.geo_widget1 = GeoWidget()
        self.geo_widget2 = GeoWidget()

        self.registerField("coordinate1", self.geo_widget1)
        self.registerField("coordinate2", self.geo_widget2)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.geo_widget1)
        lay.addWidget(self.geo_widget2)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QWizard()
    page = WizardPage()
    w.addPage(page)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have had it working however it just shows a blank screen now I am attempting to implement the feedback. I have tried to pick up as much as I can from the documents but not being able to debug qml is causing issues as I don't even know if onClicked can do two things at once (eg. emit the coordinates to the spinboxes and add a feedback circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several things not defined so I will delete them. On the other hand, center is a property, it is not a function, so what you must do is assign the position. It should also be noted that the radius of MapCircle is in meters and not in pixels, so you must choose an appropriate value for the zoom you use.

```
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.0

Item {
    width: 600
    height: 600

    Map {
        id: map

        anchors.fill: parent
        zoomLevel: 6
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(0, 0)

        MapCircle {
            id: circle

            radius: 100000
            border.width: 1
            color: 'green'
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mouse

            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                var pos = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y));
                circle.center = pos;
                controller.update_from_map(pos);
            }
        }

        plugin: Plugin {
            name: "osm"
        }

    }

}
```